# Why Vectorized PDF images have a resolution property

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a bit confused why would a vectorized image have a resolution property? Shouldn't it be vectorized and gives you any size?

Ok, I made a little test on Xcode and printed the width and the height of a pdf image. I noticed its 3 multiplied by the resolution. (Tested on 3x device screen).

```
let imageRef = (imageView.image?.cgImage)!
let size = imageRef.bytesPerRow * imageRef.height
print(imageRef.width)
print(imageRef.height)
```

As you may know, at compile time Xcode generates the 1x, 2x and 3x images from the PDF image. Those image sizes are decided by Xcode depending on the resolution of the PDF image. Which adds up with the results of the test.

Can I conclude that the pdf images need to be in a resolution of the pixel size of it on a 1x device template? What about the generated images are they going to be pixelised?

Also, the pdfs shouldn't have a resolution a lot higher than the wanted 1x size otherwise they might have a memory implications. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF is vector -- sort of.  You can still have raster elements in the PDF (embedded images, and sometime drop shadows for instance) and for such images you should still be using PNG.  Otherwise you are correct in that when apple first added PDF support to the asset catalog (iOS8), the PDF's would be rasterized at compile time.  It turns out that this isn't always desirable because sometimes you want to be able to use the same vector asset at different point sizes (not just pixel sizes) in the same app, so they added the option to "preserve vector data" (iOS 11).  If you check this then the asset gets saved a pdf and rasterization is deferred until you ask for it.

So to answer your two questions:

1. Your pdf should be in the **point** size (not pixel size) that you want (ie 1x) and the system will always scale it according to the screen scale (ie 1x,2x,3x or possibly something else in the future).
2. If you use "preserve vector data" and your pdf has no raster elements then it shouldn't matter what point size it is as far a memory goes (the size of the vector will be proportional to the complexity of the curves in the pdf and not its pixel size).  However, once it's rasterized it will indeed take up memory proportional to the size of the rasterized image.

Comment: I am not sure about what you are saying regarding "preserve vector data". I did the test above in the question with different point sizes and with and without "preserve vector data" checked. test gives same values. any ideas?

Comment: Your test should give the same values, because you are testing the CGImage, which is the rasterized form of the image; ie they both get rasterized to the same thing.  If you want to see the difference with preserve vector data on, but a very small image into a very large image view and scale it to fill.  It will be correctly rasterized at the higher resolution with "preserve vector data" on, but will be interpolated up and blurry with "preserve vector data" off

Comment: does what you mentioned regarding "preserve vector data" apply to storyboard? if not to wht method does it apply?

Comment: so why we have the pdfs with point size (1x). why not 0.5x or 0.01x ? since it get scaled?

Comment: Coregraphics renders in points and not pixels.  This allows developers to use the same sized elements across devices with different pixel densities.  ie you can use a 14 point font on a 1x iPad and it will be more or less the same size as a 14 point font on a 3x iPhone X max, even though the iPhone X max will actually use 9 times as many pixels to render the same text.  This is why your pdfs should be in points and not pixels, so they match the size of the core graphics drawing context and not the pixels of the device.

Comment: I mean why we don't lower the resolution of the pdfs as much as we want. it doesn't have to be 1x with "preserve vector data" checked. right?

Comment: if I have an imageView with 200x200 points size in a 3x device. And my pdf resolution is 100x100 and "preserve vector data" is checked. would be there any implications?

Comment: it should be 1x because when you design it on screen 1x should be roughly the same size on you screen s it is on the iPhone (ie ~72 points per inch).  You don't save any memory by making it smaller since the raster file size is based on the number of curves and not the size of the curves, so you might as well save it at the size its actually going to be shown at.

Comment: unless it going to be used in multiple places with different sizes as you mentioned. I go with the lower :D.

Comment: I may save disk space :)

Comment: I wasn't arguing that it saves memory that already well explained by you before. I was just wondering.

Comment: It looks like I was on drugs that day. What I was arguing! ty for the answer @Josh Homann

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a matter of how much work the asset catalog has to do in advance and how much work the system has to do at runtime. If your PDF is only for use at 1x, 2x, and 3x, the asset catalog can pre-render it when the app is built and so it takes no time at all for the runtime to draw it. But if you intend to show this PDF at *other* sizes, the runtime must perform that rendering. So you only preserve vector data in the latter case.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some other vector formats (like SVG), PDFs do have dimensions to them, although they are in points, not pixels. You can see the dimensions of your PDF in Preview - open the file, and go to the Tools menu -> Show Inspector. Then, click the Crop ruler.